# convert web application to android and ios application

Tags: php, android, ios, mysql, web-applications

I designed and programmed web application like the website but has more processing in the admin page...
after that the customers ask me to convert it to the application , So, can I convert it traditional by any online website to application converter which takes the link of the website and converts it to .apk
are this method is correct?? or it has a bad effect in futures when the number of users is increased???
Note:- the web program or site that I build it is programmed in PHP in backend and HTML, CSS, javascript and bootstrap in front end
can anyone help and advise me pLz???

Comment: No there is no apk generator like that . You have Php as backend and it can be used to make both Android & IOS applications. You have to make applications for your site separately.

Comment: You can load your pages in `WebView`, check it [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/12/android-working-with-webview-building-a-simple-in-app-browser/)

Comment: I mean like online converted https://gonative.io/ @Abhishek Sharma

Comment: They are not converting it directly. They have different pricing for different features of Android & IOS application. And they will give you a sample app first,after that they will code differently for your application.There is no shortcut

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as website to apk converter unfortunately.
You have to build the android application separately.

You can use your PHP models with CURL to call as API from Android.
This article can help:
[click](http://%20https://www.weichieprojects.com/blog/curl-api-calls-with-php/)

or

You can build Android app only containing webviews and you can call each webpage in different webviews.
Click [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview) for help for working with webviews in android.

Comment: I mean like online converted gonative.io

Comment: @TaifFadhil gonative is only online converter I know of...but they also uses webviews as far as  my knowledge. You can use gonative but its not free. or you can just create webviews in native android.

Comment: yes, I want just to view of this page, my question is any risk of using this method???

Comment: No, as per my knowledge there is no risk for taking this approach.